# Deleting and logging out user causes invalid session token Swift Parse Server

Tags: ios, swift, session, parse-server

I've done this before and not had any problems. All I'm doing is deleting the current user and if that is successful logging them out and going back to the sign up view. I use the below code. This is the issue.

If a user signs up, I can delete and log them out successfully once. But if another user is created and I try to delete and log them out the user is deleted and when the logout attempts I got the error: `Invalid session token.`

Any help is much appreciated. Also please let me know if theres any other relevant code I can add.

```
PFUser.current()?.deleteInBackground(block: { (success, error) in

    if error != nil {

        print(error)

    } else {

        PFUser.logOutInBackground(block: { (error) in

            if error != nil {

                print(error)

            } else {

                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showLoginSignupView", sender: self)
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised this would work even the first time. If you've deleted a user, there is no user to log out. Try switching the order of those functions. Sign them out, then delete the user. You may need a cloud function for this so that the User can be deleted with the master key, as users should not have public destroy permissions.